# Why javascript code is not being called when I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call javascript code but when I click on debugging in devtools in Chrome the javascript is not being called, so I was wondering why is that.

This is my HTML code:

```
    <a href="" data-icon="grid" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="none"
onclick="ws.su.waypoints.editPopup(this,',id,');">
                        Edit
                    </a>
```

I have a js file with this in it:

```
(function(ws){
    ws.su = {
waypoints: {
            editPopup: function (elem, id) {
                var popup = $.mobile.activePage.find('#su-waypoint-edit');
                var schmElem = popup.find('[data-schema]');
                var tmp = $($A.getArchetypeTemplate(schmElem));
                tmp.attr('data-item', id);
                $A.archetypeSectionRefreshData(schmElem);
                popup.popup('open');
            }
        }

}

    })(ws != undefined ? ws : {});
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

This is the code that's working:

```
<a href="" data-icon="grid" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="none"
                           onclick="ws.su.users.editPopup(this,',id,');">
                            Edit
                        </a>
```

Javascript code:

```
(function(ws){
    ws.su = {
         users: {
            editPopup: function(elem, id){
                var popup = $.mobile.activePage.find('#su-popup-edit-user');
                var schmElem = popup.find('[data-schema]');
                var tmp = $($A.getArchetypeTemplate(schmElem));
                tmp.attr('data-item', id);
                $A.archetypeSectionRefreshData(schmElem);
                popup.popup('open');
            }
    }
})(ws != undefined ? ws : {});
```

so I don't understand why this one isn't.

Comment: You're passing the literal string `',id,'` as an argument to the function, not the value of an `id` variable.

Comment: Is `ws` already defined before you call the IIFE?

Comment: This is the code that is working: http://pastie.org/private/i0iy2pagqiksscvenduyxq     So I don't understand why this one is not.

Comment: Do you have both Javascript codes in the same page?

Comment: Yes, and I actually I get this error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).  And even if I wanted to execute it as ws.su.users.editPopup(this,',id,'); It should execute the users code like in the one that is working correct? Because is not executing it and actually is spitting out the same error in the console.

Comment: When you assign to `ws.su`, you're replacing the old `ws.su` that has a `waypoints` property with one that only has `users`. It doesn't merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `ws.su`, not merging it with the new properties. Use:

```
(function(ws){
    ws.su = ws.su || {};
    ws.su.waypoints = ws.su.waypoints || {};
    ws.su.waypoints.editPopup = function (elem, id) {
        var popup = $.mobile.activePage.find('#su-waypoint-edit');
        var schmElem = popup.find('[data-motocol-schema]');
        var tmp = $($A.getArchetypeTemplate(schmElem));
        tmp.attr('data-motocol-item', id);
        $A.archetypeSectionRefreshData(schmElem);
        popup.popup('open');
    }
})(ws != undefined ? ws : {});
```

Comment: Hold on, thanks for the response. This was my old code but I already fixed that problem and I still get the same problem. Thanks for pointing that out. Let me edit my question.